# Handling URLs with ui-router's ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a file called `menu.json` like such:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Search"
    "icon": "icon-search",
    "state": "search"
  },
  {
    "label": "Help",
    "icon": "icon-question-sign",
    "state": "http://help.abc.com"
  }
]
```

This file is processed and returned by the server.  I use it to render my navbar through the ngRepeat directive.

```
<li ng-repeat="entry in menu_entries">
  <!-- 'entry' is each json object in the above array -->
  <a ui-sref="{{entry.state}}"><i class="{{entry.icon}} icon-white"></i> {{entry.label}}</a>
</li>
```

The states work great, and get compiled to proper html links, however what do I do for states that are actually URLs?  Must I write some kind of ui-router *urlRouterProvider rule* OR *otherwise function*?  How do you guys handle this when there's a mix of states & urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases I have a bit different json file structure - I have attribute called `internal: true/fase` for each menu item and then have simple if statement to render link in different attribute.